# Layer Control: Link two overlays, removing overlay A removes overlay B, too

Tags: leaflet

I'd like to have some markers in my map grouped into an overlay to be able to toggle visibility of all the markers via Leaflet's layer control. Then I want to add tooltips to be permanently visible. But they should have their own overlay in order to toggle their visibility via layer control.

Of course displaying ONLY the labels without the markers does not make much sense, i.e. I'd like to "link" the overlays:
- user turns markers off: labels disappear automatically
- user turns markers on: only markers appear
- user turns labels on: markers are automatically added.

I have the overlays and can toggle them using layer control. Auto-adding the missing overlay (event handler 1) is working like a charm.

But trying to auto-remove the labels in event handler 2 Leaflet starts firing various "overlayadd" and "overlayremove" events and NOTHING is happening, it seems like the click on the layer control checkbox didn't even happen.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.5.1/dist/leaflet.css" integrity="sha512-xwE/Az9zrjBIphAcBb3F6JVqxf46+CDLwfLMHloNu6KEQCAWi6HcDUbeOfBIptF7tcCzusKFjFw2yuvEpDL9wQ==" crossorigin=""/>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.5.1/dist/leaflet.js" integrity="sha512-GffPMF3RvMeYyc1LWMHtK8EbPv0iNZ8/oTtHPx9/cc2ILxQ+u905qIwdpULaqDkyBKgOaB57QTMg7ztg8Jm2Og==" crossorigin=""></script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="mapid" style="width: 600px; height: 400px;"></div>
<script>
    var position = [51.5, -0.09];
      var map = L.map('mapid').setView(position, 13);

    var layerControl = new L.Control.Layers().addTo(map);

    // add layers
    var markers = new L.LayerGroup().addTo(map);
    layerControl.addOverlay(markers, "Markers");
    var labels = new L.LayerGroup().addTo(map);
    layerControl.addOverlay(labels, "Labels");

    // add marker and label to layers
    var marker = L.marker(position);
    var label = L.marker(position, {
      icon: L.divIcon(),
      opacity: 0
    }).bindTooltip("Hello", { permanent: true, offset: [-12, -30] });
    markers.addLayer(marker);
    labels.addLayer(label);

    // bind event handlers

    // 1) this is working: if enabling labels auto-enable markers, too
    map.on("overlayadd", function(event) {
      if (event.layer === labels) {
        markers.addTo(map);
        layerControl._update();
      }
    });

    // 2) this does not work:
    map.on("overlayremove", function(event) {
      if (event.layer === markers) {
        console.log("does not remove anything");
        labels.remove();
        layerControl._update();
      }
    });
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Full example: https://codesandbox.io/s/jovial-clarke-jrxjp

Comment: Use `L.LayerGroup`s instead. Make groups of one marker plus its label.

Comment: Forgot to mention that I actually am using LayerGroups. I added the full sample code here: https://codesandbox.io/s/react-leaflet-map-with-marker-zjq5y

Comment: Please edit your question to include all relevant code in the question itself. Also, please spend a few minutes to read through https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example